# Mysql using count in query

Tags: mysql, sql

Say that I have two tables T and T1

T

```
id   p   o 
 1    47  1
 2    48  2
 3    49  25
```

T1

```
     id   p   o 
     1    47  1
     2    42  2
     3    47  25
```

I am looking to insert rows from T1 into T if `count(T1.p)>1`

T

```
   id   p   o 
     1    47  1
     2    48  2
     3    49  25
     1    47  1
     3    47  25
```

I tried the following query but it didn't work

```
insert into T(id , p,o)(SELECT T1.id , T1.p1,T1.l FROM T1 
                        where SELECT count(*) FROM t1 
                        GROUP BY t1.p 
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

For more [details](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d96f) . 
Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: remove the () around the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those values into T you will have to find out who they are in T1 and JOIN them with T1 again, to get the right number of rows:

```
INSERT INTO T (id, p, o)
SELECT TT.*
FROM T1 TT
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, p1, l
  FROM T1
  GROUP BY p1
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) a ON a.p1 = TT.p1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebaf7/1)</kbd>

How this works:

```
SELECT id, p1, l
FROM T1
GROUP BY p1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Returns the p1 that appears more than once in the table. This returns p1 = 47. `GROUP BY p1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` makes sure that for each p1, we only want the results that appear more than once.

Then, we do an inner JOIN with T1 again, to get all rows that have P1 = 47:

```
ID  P1  L
1   47  1
3   47  25
```

Then you just INSERT this result in the destination table.

Comment: Could you please explain me how you successfully get the two rows (1, 47, 1)and (
3, 47, 25)

Comment: @user3014966. I added a little explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into T SELECT T1.id , T1.p1,T1.l FROM T1 
GROUP BY t1.p1 
HAVING COUNT(t1.p1)>1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75c8e/1

Use dml on the left side

Comment: It is returning only 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in your select.

This should get you going:

```
SELECT T1.id , T1.p1,T1.l 
                         FROM t1 
                        GROUP BY t1.p1 
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c395c/1)

EDIT:  Updated the SQL Fiddle to include the insert.

Comment: It is returning only 1 row.

Comment: Yes, that's because your select is only returning one row. If you group by p1, only one row in the result has a count of > 1.

Answer (score 1):

The below SQL should do what your looking for:

```
INSERT INTO T (id, p, o)
SELECT id, p1, l
FROM T1
WHERE p1 IN (
  SELECT p1
  FROM T1
  GROUP BY p1
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

[SQL Fiddle - Final result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/698fb/4/0)